# node http-server не находит папку

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Использую http-server из npm, структура файлов такая:

- http-server
- node_modules
- public

  - index.html;    js;    css

> src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"
>   подключаю angular

Не находит его, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [инструкции](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server#usage):

> ### Использование:
>
> ```
> http-server [path] [options]
> ```
>
> `[path]` по умолчанию `./public`, если эта папка существует, а иначе `./`.

Сервер отдаёт папку `public`, она является корнем сайта. А `node_modules` в ней нет.

Что делать, вариантов много.

Неплохой вариант — собрать одну здоровенную JSину со всеми зависимостями куда-нибудь в `public` с помощью какого-нибудь бандлера, коих много. Сходу назову [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) и [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Ещё можно установить AngularJS иначе, через Bower, [сказав ему размещать модули в `public` следующим содержимым в `.bowerrc` в папке проекта](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14080568/2076787):

```
{
  "directory" : "public/components"
}
```

Ещё можно сконфигурировать вебсервер на отдачу файлов по разным адресам из разных папок. Но это уже если вы **не** будете пользоваться `http-server`ом.

---

Быстрый и грязный ход это сделать симлинк ([символьную ссылку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)) в `public` к местонахождению ангуляра. Специально не буду приводить готовую команду, потому что это опасный приём, которым стоит пользоваться только если вы точно понимаете, что делаете.